# Formula displays as text regardless of NumberFormat being set to General

Tags: excel, vba

Okay, so my issue is regardless of the NumberFormat being set my formula still displays as text until I go into the cell and hit enter. What I am trying to do is dynamically create a new column and fill a range from row 5 -> 500 with a formula. My full code is below, I have tried different variations like setting the format specifically to the output of the formula, moved the `.NumberFormat =` inside the `With` block after the formula is set.

I have also tried `.Calculate` on the range to try and get it to recalculate. It doesnt matter how simple the formula is, it still just doesnt like it.

```
Sub AddHaulageRows()
    If ActiveSheet.Name Like "WK*" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "WTemplate" Then
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 16).Value <> "Haulage Rate" Then
             Columns("P:P").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
             ', CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
             ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 16).Value = "Haulage Rate"
             ActiveSheet.Range("P5:P500").NumberFormat = "General"
            With ActiveSheet.Range("P5:P500")
                'Setting formula to the most simplest thing I can do.
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=TRUE"
             End With
        Else
            Columns("P:P").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
    Else
    MsgBox "Cannot add row as this is not a valid weekly sheet.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

The weird thing is it works on some sheets in my workbook, but not others. On some sheets it just gives an `1004 Application-defined or object-defined` error. The sheets all conform to the same template.

Comment: That might be a more evil manifestation of [this](http://superuser.com/q/299437/52365). You might need to perform the `value` trick first, then set the formula.

Comment: That code works fine for me, but you also say it works for you sometimes. I agree with @GSerg that forcing the `value` of the cells would be the quick and easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

first i would try this:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("P5:P500")
  .NumberFormat = "General"
  .FormulaR1C1 = "=TRUE"
End With
```

sometimes seperate formatting causes an override